# Using setOption function with memcache in php

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcached, libmemcache

I am using [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) extension for connecting and playing around with the Memcache server.
But now, I want to use a function that is not present in this library but present in Memcached called [Memcached::setOption](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.setoption.php)

Its really difficult for me to move the entire code from Memcache to Memcached.

Is there any way by which I can use the functionality of the setOption function without changing the code everywhere?

Comment: `memcache` and `memcached` are functionally the same with different naming conventions. `set/get` in the first is trivially the same as `setOption/getOption`.

Comment: See this link.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php .. There is no function as `setOption`